# Is it possible to compare the md5_file of the current file in the file itself using PHP?

Tags: php

I have a "test1.php" and I want to test if the code of the file is changed or not in the file itself, how can I do this? The problem is that I am not able to get the last md5 code of the file to put into the if condition.

```
<?php

if( md5_file("test1.php") != "f94b58494ec51cedaf8b990f1346d2a7")
{
    echo "Sorry, Current file is altered.";
    exit;
}

echo "other code goes here";

?>
```

Is there any way we can know and put exit if the file code is changed?

Comment: I dont know if that is possible, but you could have same file in some other folder and then compare the hashes of the two files.

Comment: Also: What for? If it is possible to alter the file, you can also remove said statement and still use the file. Just saying :-/

Comment: Why would you want to test this? If must storing hashes of each source file in separate file would be one option.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Can you save hashes to a database and compare to the last time it was checked, then just update the database after the check with the new hash?

Comment: I want to test the code security on the localhost, I will put compare string and then I will obfuscate that file, it is just a testing I want to do.

Comment: Also how do you intend to create this if and then obfuscate? When you obfuscate the has changes obviously, so how do you intend to test after obfuscation?

Answer (score 0):

### Store MD5 in another file

The simplest way to do so is to store the MD5 hash in another file. I don't see any reason not to do this.

### Get MD5 from the internet

You could store the md5 code on a remote server

### Create a copy

1. Let the script copy itself to another location `test-copy.php`
2. open `test-copy.php`, match the md5 with some regex/the line number
3. remove the md5 from the file (so replace "f94b58494ec51cedaf8b990f1346d2a7" by "")
4. build the md5 of the new file that does not contain an md5 code
5. compare it to the matched md5 code

Answer (score 0):

In a way - yes.

```
<?php
$last_check = file_get_contents('test1.php.md5');
if (md5_file('test1.php') != $last_check){
    echo 'Sorry, Current file is altered.';
    exit;
}
// other code goes here
?>
```

Then create a `test1.php.md5` file and put the resulg of `md5_file('test1.php')` into it.

Comment: Above suggested Idea is possible, but we have to create duplicate copy of the file that I don't want to do.